# Jquerymobile alerts 2 times on pageinit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my page load, I am getting 2 alert from jqm. Any issues from my code?

My code:

```
 $(document).bind('pageinit', function () {

alert('hi') // alerts 2 times...

        if(navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1){
           $('div.video-holder span ').hide();
        }

    $('a[href="#"], a.disabled').bind('click touchstart',function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    } );

    if($(' #task-1,#task-2').length){
        candidateAccordion($('.candidate-list'));    
    }
    if($('#task-3').length || $('#task-4').length){
        taskSelector($('#task-3,#task-4'));//only for tast list selection
    }
    if($('video').length){
        $('.video-holder').each(function(num,element) {
            videoProcess($(element));
        });
    }
    if($('#task1-candSelected').length){
        candidateUpdate($('#task1-candSelected'));
    }

    if($('#task2-results').length){
        task2ResultProcess();
    }

    if($('#task3-results').length){
        task3ResultProcess();
    }
    if($('#task4-results').length){
        task4ResultProcess();
    }
    if($('#scoredUptoFinal').length){
        scoredUptoFinal();
    }

} )
```

Comment: How many pages you have inside .html file? @SergePashkevich you should have posted a new question with your data in order to assist you, not to mention, saving 50 of your rep ;)

Comment: @Omar you are right. I will post question with my data and environment. Okt Exuce me for flooding in your topic

Answer (score 1):

If your alert fires twice, the event will be triggered twice.

How about adding `event` to the function parameter and consoling it like so:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function (event) {

   console.log( event )

   ...
```

This should give you some information on what is happening.

There are a lot of questions on `pageinit` on SO (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512174/pageinit-fires-multiple-times?rq=1) ), so maybe they can point you to a solution as well.

I also had issues with multiple `pageinit` events firing. I'm usually doing this to `lock-up` a page after the first trigger:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    if ( !$('html').hasClass("mv-on") ){
        $('html').addClass("mv-on");
        // trigger my stuff
        }
    });
```

This way pageinit will run `ONCE` for the whole DOM. You could also use it to lock up pages by adding a class or attribute to a page on wich a `pageinit` event was fired.

Also, make sure `pageinit` is the correct event for your bindings/handlers. I often tried to set things on `pageinit`, like binding to an element by class, when the class I tried to bind to hasn't been inserted into the DOM yet. I'm usually going with `pagebeforeshow` now, because then I'm sure all background things are done. But just a matter of perference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a multipage template? Could be that you have two `pages` using the same id. JQM loads the first occuring page and thus would load it twice.

Could also be related to that issue pointed out in [this JQM git issue request](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3347).

Also take a look at [this chart](http://bradbroulik.blogspot.de/2011/12/jquery-mobile-events-diagram.html), really nice to understand the order of events fired by JQM.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't bind to `document` with pageinit event, could you try with one displayed page only

For example, 
`$("#yourpageId").bind('pageinit', function () {...}`

Comment: The docs say, pageinit should go on document - see [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)