# jQuery click firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Update:**

Seems like the problem has nothing to do with my code. I've been running the webpage over browser-sync and that's where the problem appears. When I open the static webpage in Chrome directly, everything seems to be working fine. Thank you to everyone for your help!

I'm working on my personal website and want to make a way to filter through my list of projects using buttons.

```
<div class="filters">
  <button class="btn btn-filter">Android</button>
  <button class="btn btn-filter">iOS</button>
  <button class="btn btn-filter">Web Dev</button>
  <button class="btn btn-filter">Data Science</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to attach event listeners to the buttons by doing this, but it seems like the event listeners are being attached multiple times:

```
$(".btn-filter").each(function() {
  console.log(this); // #1
  $(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log(this); // #2
  })
  debugger;
})
```

I have also tried using the class selector. It doesn't work, I switched to `.each()` and `$(this)` to be sure the elements were being assigned event handlers only once.

```
$('.btn-filter').click(...)
```

Logs show that each button is selected once to be assigned a click listener, but when I actually click the buttons, only some fire once, and some fire 3 times. I use some because it doesn't always behave the same way each time the page is run.

I have tried the solutions described in
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460562/click-firing-multiple-times)(`off()`, `unbind()`, `stopPropagation()`), but none have worked.

Using Google Chrome's debugger tools, it seems like at the breakpoint, `this` refers to the HTML element twice for every iteration of each, despite some clicks firing once and some three times.

I suppose I could just assign IDs and wire each button individually, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong here. Could anyone explain?

Comment: with `".btn-filter"` you already select all the buttons (with that class) and can bind one handler to all of them.

Comment: I've tried the class selector to assign a listener to each element in the class, but the result is the same. I switched to `each()` and `this` to debug

Comment: Is this code accidentally being called more than once, meaning is the `$(".btn-filter").each()` being called multiple times, for instance inside another event handler?

Comment: The code is wrapped as a function called `initButtonListeners()` and is called once on document ready

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve] as the code shown by itself shouldn't cause what you are seeing

Comment: Apologies, this is my first stackoverflow post. I'll get better I promise. On another note, is this possibly a problem with browser-sync. I've just tested it by opening the .html file in Chrome and it seems to be working fine...

Comment: I cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/2h1ygLzo/1/ - only fires once on each click. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: after your update stating it had nothing to do with your code, it would make sense to delete this question. Will be of no use for future visitors.

Comment: Before I posted the update I tried and it wouldn't let me delete it. Oh well... It might be good for people with similar problems with a program like browser-sync though.

Answer (score 6):

You are running a for each loop on the class, so it will create a new event handler for each element with the class. If you want just one event handler you need to write it like this:

```
$(".btn-filter").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Buttons that show or hide specific content are best described with a data value or id

Edit: after learning you had this before I will add that nothing you supplied is causing the error you are receiving.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify in the post; I have also tried that with the same result. I switched to the `.each()` to try to get to the bottom of whether the event handlers were actually being registered multiple times.

Comment: Note this is effectively the same as OP's code. Both use a loop to put the event listener on each element. `$(".btn-filter").click()` is just going to do the loop internally

Comment: Also, I'm a bit of a newbie when JS, so I want to be certain, I am using `.each()` on the class, but within the scope of that call, I'm using $(this) to assign the clicks, so that should just do the one element in the class, right?

Comment: You will still need to have a way to specify the action you wish to take when clicking on the button. usually this is done with an id or a data value. Otherwise the exact same code will run if you click any of the buttons

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but something is definitely happening when the button is clicked, the HTML element is logged to the console

Comment: Though I was on the same track as you, Daniel, I made a simple test with the original code. The described behaviour cannot be reproduced: http://jsfiddle.net/2h1ygLzo/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is is here

```
$(".btn-filter")**.each**(function() {
```

You should simplify it by simply doing something like this

```
$(".btn-filter").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log(e); 
  debugger;
})
```

Since you are already selecting via the class name **$(".btn-filter")** the function should be added to all the elements.

Comment: I've updated the post to clarify that this was my initial code, which didn't work and lead me to do `.each()` and `$(this)` to make sure I'm not re-registering event handlers.

Comment: Are you sure you are not initializing/declaring the function from multiple locations? T

Comment: The code is wrapped by a function and the function is called once on document ready. Also, some buttons were firing once as intended, but others 3 times, so while I had considered that, there's no problem the way I'm using it. This is looking like a browser-sync problem.

Answer (score 0):

Call click event using class and get clicked value using `.html()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-filter").click(function() {
                    alert($(this).html());
                })
    });
```

[JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/10254/)